# Eliminating NULL Values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I have a complex subquery within a query giving me this:

| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | NULL |
| NULL | value2 |
| value3 | NULL |
| NULL | value4 |
| value5 | value5 |

But instead, I need this output:

| Col 1 | Col 2 |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 |
| value3 | value4 |
| value5 | value5 |

the condition `Col1 IS NOT NULL OR Col2 IS NOT NULL` doesn't work obviously. Is there any other way to filter null values out or does the previous query have to change? I didn't want to include the wholesome script as it is not very relevant to this filtering part of the query.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: is there any row that can represent the order?

Comment: @D-Shih No, but I can add using ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: using `ROW_NUMBER` window function must use a column to represent the order otherwise it might be disorder

Comment: Both Col 1 and Col 2 are DATE values that stem from the same column of a table.

Comment: You asked if '... the previous query have to change...` but didn't give us any queries. You are combining rows, aligning certain values in Col1 with certain values from Col2 (you aligned value1,value2 into one row, for example), you need to tell us what the logic is (ie why not combine value3,value2 into one row, for example)

Comment: Maybe you can show us how do you get these 2 `Col1` & `Col2` .

Comment: The real question here is why is ok if "value1" and "value2" are on the same row? What if you had "value1" and "value5" on the same row? Is that ok? Or is there some logic to define which Col1 and Col2 can be on the same row?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a straightforward way to do what I mentioned in this question based on your comments. I changed my previous query to eliminate the need for doing this operation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your case and why you want to do this, but your question seems weird

But as far as I could understand below query might work as your expectation, I used some extra columns

Replace your sub query at particular place

```
select col1,Col2 from (
(select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by a)index1,* from 
(select 'a'a,Col1 from (YOUR SUB QUERY) t1 where col1 is not null)a)t1 full outer join
(select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by a)index1,* from 
(select 'a'a,Col2 from (YOUR SUB QUERY) t1 where col2 is not null)b)t2 on t1.index1=t2.index1)
```